# Ethcore: "The dapp cannot be reached"

Tags: dapps, parity, ethcore

On a private dev chain with two Ethcore nodes, I created a dapp as per the instructions at https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki/Tutorial-Part-I. Everything was OK and I can see the dapp listed in the Parity browser UI under **DECENTRALIZED APPLICATIONS** on the **APPLICATIONS** tab. However, when I click on it, I get just a blank page. After waiting about 10 seconds, when I refresh the page, it displays `Loading` for a few seconds and then the message `The dapp cannot be reached`

Googling for `"the dapp cannot be reached" ethcore` only gave me the Git commit page of the commit when this message was added to a Javascript source file.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: This test dApp works fine for my Parity 1.5.2. Do you try with the last version of Parity?

Comment: My Parity version is: `version Parity/v1.6.0-nightly-afa1edb-20170125/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.14.0`  .  Maybe I should get a more stable version. That does have 'nightly' in there.